# prop() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python-3.x, arguments

I'm learning python and I tried to test something to understand the @property...
this is my code:

```
class Thing:

    def __init__(self, my_word=None):
        self._word = my_word

    def word(self):
        return self._word

    def prop(func):
        def new():
            return func(self)
        return new()



thing = Thing('Im here')
thing.prop(thing.word)
```

i just get this error and its a little confusing for me.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/python projs/1/1.py", line 17, in <module>
    thing.prop(thing.word)
builtins.TypeError: prop() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error mean you give 2 parameter to the function `prop` instead of 1. When you call a function on an object (`object.function()`), it actually place the object as a paramater. You need to change :

```
def prop(self, func):
    ...
```

But there is other mistakes, you can't call `(self)` on a string (in the function new()).
But the error mean you gave to much parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give `prop` a `self` parameter.

It's implicitly passing `self` as the first argument, which means 2 arguments are being passed in total, even though it only looks like 1 is.

Comment: @shiyonsufa Well, this likely solved your original error. Whether or not there's other problems is a different story.